# Running webpack only for build scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, server, bundle

Is there any way to run webpack only for build scripts not for running webpack server?
The node server needs scripts to open the HTML file correctly.
Scripts are built by running webpack in development mode.
Is it good practise if I start webpack and node server with one command?
Something like below (using "start").

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run dev\" \"npm run server\"",
"dev": "webpack --mode=development",
"deploy": "webpack  --mode=production --config webpack.production.config.js",
"server": "nodemon ./src/server/server.js --exec babel-node",
```

Comment: "build": "webpack"

Comment: Doesn't work, because running this command doesn't create the dev folder and files inside it. 
I think the problem is with the webpack configuration contained in the webpack.config.js file.
Contents of the configuration file:
https://pastebin.com/dgYep4ni

Comment: Command: npm run dev